# Item Click grid. Change label text

Tags: extjs

I have no trouble clicking grid items and updating textfields but do you think I change a label text?  grrr

All I want to do is when I select a record set in the grid is to update the label text and text field(which it already does).

**Model**

```
Ext.define("myApp.model.ActionItem", {
    extend : "Ext.data.Model",
    fields : [
        {
            name: 'pri',
            type: 'int'
        },
        {
            name: 'request',
            type: 'int'
        }
    ]

});
```

**Controller:**

```
Ext.define("myApp.controller.HomeController", {
    extend: "Ext.app.Controller",
    id:     "HomeController",
    refs: [
        { ref: "ActionItemsGrid",    selector: "[xtype=actionitemgrid]" },
        { ref: "DetailsPanel",       selector: "[xtype=actionitemdetails]" }
    ],
    pri: "",
    models: ["ActionItem"],
    stores: ["myActionStore"],
    views:
        [
            "home.ActionItemDetailsPanel",
            "home.ActionItemGrid",
            "home.HomeScreen"
        ],
    init: function () {
        this.control({
            "#homescreen": {
                beforerender: this.loadActionItems
            },
            "ActionItemsGrid": {
                itemclick: this.displayDetails
            }
        });
    },
    displayDetails: function (model, record) {
        this.getDetailsPanel().loadRecord(record);
    },
    loadActionItems: function () {
        var store = Ext.getStore("myActionStore");
        store.load();
        this.getActionItemsGrid().reconfigure(store);
    }
});
```

**View**

```
Ext.define("myApp.view.home.ActionItemDetailsPanel", {
    extend : "Ext.form.Panel",
    xtype: "actionitemdetails",
    items: [
                {

                    xtype: "fieldset", defaults: { xtype: "textfield", disabled: true },
                    items: [
                        {
                            xtype: 'label',
                            forId: 'pri',
                            text: 'My Priority',
                            margin: '0 0 0 10'
                        },
                        { id: "pri",          fieldLabel: "Priority" },
                        { id: "request",      fieldLabel: "Requested Time" }
                    ]
                }
            ]
});
```

Comment: What have you tried? What is the problem? Why not just call the `setText` method? http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.0-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.form.Label-method-setText

Comment: Thanks for responding Evan.  I'm still new to the language so bare with me here.  My understanding is that because loadform is a method of Form it will match it to the item ID's in Ext.form.panel?  So in my example this works provided the field is a text field.  But if it's a label it doesn't do anything.  As for what I've tried you can see from my view I put in a label field and gave it an id of 'pri'.  It's the only thing I can think of right now.

Comment: Sorry...*loadRecord   (typeO)  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution from Condor a while ago.   http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?106256-Form-Panel-Load-Record-and-show-the-data-in-form-label

The gist of it is that label is not a field.  So in order to do what I want I need an xtype: 'displayfield' with the name of the field I want.

```
{
    xtype: 'displayfield',
    name: 'pri',
    text: 'My Priority',
    margin: '0 0 0 10'
}
```